# Ada error: invalid use of subtype mark in expression or call

Tags: ada, subtype

I'm stuck here with an error in my Ada program. There is a lot of code and I don't want to copy all of it here, so I hope that the part that I'm sharing is the part from where the problem comes.

```
   task type Producent is
       entry Start(Jedzenie: in Typ_Jedzenia; Czas_Produkcji: in Integer);
   end Producent;

   task type Buffer is
       entry Zamow(Jedzenie: in Typ_Jedzenia; Numer: in Integer; Czy_Zatwierdzono: out Boolean);
       entry Dostarcz(Zamowienie: in Typ_Zestawu; Numer: out Integer);
   end Buffer;


task body Producent is
  package Losowa_Produkcja is new
    Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random(Zakres_Czasu_Produkcji);
  Generator: Losowa_Produkcja.Generator;
  Index_Jedzenia: Integer;
  Nr_Produkcji_Jedzenia: Integer := 1;
  Produkcja: Integer;
  Zatwierdzono: Boolean := False;
  
begin
  accept Start (Jedzenie : in Typ_Jedzenia; Czas_Produkcji : in Integer) do
     Losowa_Produkcja.Reset(Generator);
     Index_Jedzenia := Jedzenie;
     Produkcja := Czas_Produkcji;
  end Start;
    
  loop
     delay Duration(Losowa_Produkcja.Random(Generator));
     Put_Line("Przygotowano " & Nazwa_Jedzenia(Index_Jedzenia) & " numer " & Integer'Image(Nr_Produkcji_Jedzenia));
     
     loop
        Buffer.Zamow(Index_Jedzenia, Nr_Produkcji_Jedzenia, Zatwierdzono); <-------- ERROR
        if Zatwierdzono = False then
           Put_Line("Brak miejsca w kuchni dla " & Nazwa_Jedzenia(Index_Jedzenia) & ". Wstrzymanie");
           delay Duration(3.0);
        else
           Nr_Produkcji_Jedzenia := Nr_Produkcji_Jedzenia + 1;
        end if;
        exit;
     end loop;
  end loop;
end Producent;

task body Buffer is
  begin
  Put_Line("Jestesmy u Buffera");
  loop
     select
        accept Zamow(Jedzenie: in Typ_Jedzenia; Numer: in Integer; Czy_Zatwierdzono: out Boolean) do
           Put_Line("Trwa zamawianie...");
        end Zamow;
     end select;
  end loop;
end Buffer;
```

From my attempts I understand that when I want to call entry `Buffer.Zamow(Index_Jedzenia, Nr_Produkcji_Jedzenia, Zatwierdzono);` (which is in task `Producent`) there is an error with 'Zatwierdzono' argument. When I removed this argument from declarations and definitions `Zamow()` entry worked.

Full error: invalid use of subtype mark in expression or call

What should I change or where is the problem with this boolean `Zatwierdzono` variable?
`Zatwierdzono` means `Accepted` in this case.
Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Possibly relevant : there would appear to be a type mismatch on the first parameter of that entry call. But as mwe don't have the full code or the fuss error message (which would include line:character and possibly other information, anything more is guesswork. Try making a minimal testcase...

Comment: At the point of the call (`Buffer.Zamow`) that is giving you the error, the only thing visible named Buffer is a type: `task type Buffer`. You cannot call a type. You need a task which is an object of the type (`O : Buffer;`) and then you can call the entries of that task: `O.Zamow`.

Comment: Or maybe you don’t need task _types_? How many instances will there be? `task Buffer is ...`

Comment: Thank you @JeffreyR.Carter, that was it. I haven't seen earlier that I'm trying to call an entry for a task type, not an object of this type. Mixed names... Thanks again so much!

Answer (score 4):

You have two problems:

```
Index_Jedzenia := Jedzenie;
```

In your Start entry is trying to implicitly convert Jedzenie from its type, Typ_Jedzenia, to Integer, the type of Index_Jedzenia.  You need some way to convert this.

Additionally on the line you are seeing the error on, the first parameter of that entry is of type Typ_Jedzenia but you are passing in an Integer (Index_Jedzenia is an integer).  Again, you can't implicitly convert types like that.

If Typ_Jedzenia is actually an integer, you can explicitly convert them.  Otherwise you need to make a conversion function of some type and use that before passing in or assigning to different types.

Comment: Thank you :) I mixed task type name with task type object name and that was the main problem,  the conversion is another thing but I've handled it somehow. Thanks!